# How to get index of the last character in a sentence

Tags: python

I have a text file with some names and their high score next to each other:

```
Sam w:10 
John S:9
Benjamin:4
```

I wondered if there was a way to get the index of last character of each because they are different lengths and I need them all for sorting.

Comment: You could split string by `:` and get last character of first part

Comment: The index of the last character is the length of the string minus one.

Comment: Do you want to get the index of the character just before the colon? And do the records have the same format like this?

Comment: This seems like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You shouldn't need the index in order to sort, you just need to split it into two parts by the `:`.

Comment: How would you split it into 2 parts using the ':'?

Comment: @Sam Ward `split` separates a string by delimiter and returns list of strings. See my answer

Answer (score 1):

you can use `str[-1].` or even `str[len(str)-1]`

Answer (score 0):

```
line.split(':')[-1]
```

will give you the score (even if it's more than one digit)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get a score to sort records you could use

```
a = "SomeName : 123"
score_a = int(a.split(':')[-1].strip())
```

or, if you are confident that `:` occurs only once

```
a = "SomeName : 123"
score_a = int(a.partition(':')[-1].strip())
```